# can i put variable in option into render controller?

Tags: symfony, twig

```
<div id="sidebar">
    {% render "AcmeIndexBundle:Default:index4" with {'max': {{ idUser }} } %}
</div>
```

It's possible this?
why return to me this error

A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in AcmeIndexBundle:Default:index2.html.twig at line 27

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,

```
{% render "AcmeIndexBundle:Default:index4" with {'max': idUser } %}
```